# Are the SO(3) defining representation and Spin 1 the same?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics

Since the equation
$$\langle j,m^\prime|J_\pm|j,m\rangle =\sqrt{(j\mp m)(j\pm m+1)} \delta_{m^\prime,m+1}$$
holds both for spin 1 (the $\underline{1}$ rep for SU(2)) and angular momentum (SO(3)). Does this mean the explicit form of spin 1 generators:
$$S_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
S_y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -i & 0 \\
i & 0 & -i \\
0 & i & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
S_z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0& -1
\end{array}\right),$$
can be obtained by a similar transformation from SO(3) generators?
$$
M_{23}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
M_{31}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
M_{12}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
.$$
Sorry to ask such basis questions. I just don't know how to solve the matrix equation $SAS^{-1}=B$.

Further, if it is not, does this mean a same set of algebra usually does not have a unique set of solution? If it is, then they are equivalent; then how could they behave differently, in terms of the global property of two groups SU(2) and SO(3)?

Comment: Your spin matrices $S_y$ and $S_z$ are wrong. $S_z$ does not have a $1/\sqrt{2}$ in front. $S_y$ is not hermitian as it stands. The $1$ should be replaced by $i$.

Comment: Yeah Thank you @Fabian. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different conventions. While the spin-matrices are in the quantum notation (that is they are Hermitian matrices), the angular momentum matrices are in conventional representation theory notation (they are anti-Hermitian matrices). In order to compare the two, you should multiply the latter by $i$. In this case, the angular moment matrices read
$$
M_{23}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -i \\
0 & i & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
M_{31}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & i \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-i & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
M_{12}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -i & 0 \\
i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
.
$$

With this, it is a straightforward exercise to show that 
$$ U=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$
does the job; e.g., $S_z = U M_{12} U^\dagger$ and so on.

Comment: Then, since they are exactly the same thing, can you tell me why would we have $SO(3)/Z_3=SU(2)$ globally? Why don't we have $SO(3)=SU(2)$? @Fabian.

Comment: Spin 1 is the same. SU(2) however also has half-integer spin representations (which SO(3) is lacking).

Comment: By the way, it should read $SU(2)/Z_2 = SO(3)$.

Comment: Yes Yes...   I was in a rush indeed.  now I know $SU(2)/Z_2=SO(3)$ is a claim depending on specific representation.  Thank you sir. good day!  @Fabian